# Statistical significance of Lift (Interest) measure for association rule mining

Tags: statistics, data-mining, apriori, arules

Is there a way to determine the statistical significance (p-values) for lift measures of interestingness for association rule mining?

Answer (score 0):

Lift measures the dependence of the LHS and the RHS. The [chi-squared](https://michael.hahsler.net/research/association_rules/measures.html) statistics for the test of independence can be converted into a p-value (most tools like arules will do that for you). Alternatively, [Fishers exact test](https://michael.hahsler.net/research/association_rules/measures.html#fishersExactTest) produces a p-values. Both measures are available via the function [`interestMeasures()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/topics/interestMeasure) in arules.